# how can you format just the time of a DateTime object in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I have a DateTime object.  How can I print just the time and in the following format:

```
 5:50 PM
```

or

```
 3:30 AM
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
yourDateTimeVariable.ToString("h:mm tt");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("h:mm tt", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-us")));
```

try this

Answer (score 2):

Try doing .ToShortTimeString() on your date object.  For example:

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
```